# Imgur notice overlaps the upload popup's border

Tags: bug, design, uploader, responsive-design

On the insert image, the popup Imgur notice overlaps the upload popup's border for small screens (the image is taken on desktop Firefox with a narrow window, but the issue is also affects ruSO on my phone's Chrome browser due to long words in translations):

> [image: Imgur notice in English]

You can see that there is enough space between buttons and text to feel the block content more evenly.

> [image: Native image from ruSO on my phone]